# Shrinkable mat-toolbar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I used the example provided here to set up a responsive navbar

https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/responsive-navbar-angular-flex-layout/

and my code looks pretty similar

```html
<div style="height: 85vh;">

  <mat-toolbar color="primary" mat-scroll-shrink>
    <span>{{title}}</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">
      <!-- The following menu items will be hidden on both SM and XS screen sizes -->
      <a href="#" mat-button>Home</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button>About</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button>Services</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button>Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button>Start</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button>FAQ</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button>Blog</a>
      <a href="#" mat-button>Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <a href="#" (click)="sidenav.open()">Show Side Menu</a>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav fxLayout="column">
      <div fxLayout="column">
        <a (click)="sidenav.close()" href="#" mat-button>Close</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Home</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>About</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Services</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Start</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>FAQ</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Blog</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Contact</a>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>

      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
      <p>Demoing some content to make this thing scroll</p>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

What I would like to have happen is have the mat-toolbar shrink as I scroll down, which is common in a lot of sites, such as this one:

https://www.havealook.com.au/

I won't post the rest of the angular 5 code, just follow the example to re-create - its pretty quick.

I've looked at the materials website here

https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview

but there's not much explanation on how to add to it, and I'm pretty new to this stuff. Does anyone know how I might customise this to make the toolbar shrink, based on scrolling?

Comment: have you got any progress on solving this problem

Comment: None, actually. I have been working on other problems. The problem is, I'm not sure how to detach the toolbar in the layout without messing up the mat-sidenav-content, and also detecting the right point in the scroll to trigger the compaction is hard too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Update Nov 2018

The `ScrollDispatchModule` was deprecated with Angular CDK v7. Use the `ScrollingModule` instead.

---

I've created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sv3klu?embed=1&file=app/toolbar-multirow-example.ts) with a toolbar that shrinks when scrolling down.

### Main Steps

#### Use the `CdkScrollDispatcher` service to react to scroll events

1. Import the `ScrollDispatchModule` in your module.

```js
import {ScrollDispatchModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
```

2. Mark the containers of which the scroll events are relevant with the directive `cdkScrollable`, here it is `mat-sidenav-content`.

```html
 <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill cdkScrollable>
```

3. React to scroll events in the `ngOnInit` of your component, get the `scrollTop` position and set a flag if it is larger than a certain threshold:

```js
private readonly SHRINK_TOP_SCROLL_POSITION = 50;
shrinkToolbar = false;

constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher,
            private ngZone: NgZone) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled()
    .pipe(
      map((event: CdkScrollable) => event.getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollTop)
    )
    .subscribe(scrollTop => this.ngZone.run(() => this.shrinkToolbar = scrollTop > this.SHRINK_TOP_SCROLL_POSITION ? true : false));
}
```

You need to run this with `ngZone` because `scrolled()` events of the `ScrollDispatcher` are run outside of Angular by default. Without it, the ChangeDetection won't run and your templates won't be updated.

#### Change the toolbar layout on scroll

1. Add a shrink css class, when the container is scrolled down

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary" [ngClass]="{'shrink-toolbar': shrinkToolbar}">
```

2. Define the css class for the *shrinked* layout.

```css
.shrink-toolbar {
  height: 32px;
}
```

Find more information about the scroll service in the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview).

Comment: dude! love your work! that was perfect. The official docs could do with your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: @KimKern Thanks for your answer as well! Unfortunately your Stackblitz link is pointing to a different example.

Comment: @stevo I have recreated the stackblitz.

Comment: @KimKern have you maybe also a solution that feels like this: https://osvaldas.info/examples/auto-hide-sticky-header/?lazy-plus ? I also opend a feature request here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16659 But i am sure they will need some months, maybe years to implement it =/

Comment: @Budi You just have to take into account the scrolling direction (e.g. `oldValue - newValue > 0`). Otherwise it's pretty much the same as in my post.

Comment: can you make maybe an example? i think we need to place behind the out sliding element a block element like a empty div that simulates the height of the outscroll value. that the content area grow correctly. i was not able to do this in last days.