# Event on scrolling

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I have been trying to make my toolbar shrink after scrolling down for the last 9 hours...

I tried "scrollDispatcher" example here: [Shrinkable mat-toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454369/shrinkable-mat-toolbar)

but it tells me "Cannot find name 'map'." in:

```
.pipe(
map((....
```

I tried this (html):

```
<mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill cdkScrollable>
```

(ts):

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled()
      .subscribe(event=> console.log('you have scrolled'))
}
```

but also doesn't do anything when scrolling...

did angular team change that? how do I solve it?

Comment: map is an operator in rxjs6, you aren't getting any console logs?

Comment: Did you import `map`? It's now a pipeable operator and should be imported like `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`;

Comment: yea I tried to import map but same issue... also the last example I dont get anything in console log..