# How to handle window scroll in angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

@HostListener("window:scroll", []) is working fine with angular but when we are using with material it not works because `<mat-drawer-container fullscreen>` tag it will virtually take browser height and scroll within it.
i mean actual windows is not scrolling. so hares the problem comes.
then my question is how to fire event when `<mat-drawer-content></mat-drawer-content>` scroll instead of window scroll

Answer (score 3):

mat-drawer-content has the method elementScrolled(), which returns an Observable of type Event. Check the API ref https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

Comment: Thanks :) and we also do from cdk ways :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454369/shrinkable-mat-toolbar